# What do "out for" and "caring" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading a book which is about salesman. The book has a sentence as follows:

> the traditional view of a salesman who is good with customers will always be that he is only out for selling his products and does not care about customers or relationships with customers (as if selling products is not caring, and as if relationships with customers do not include selling products).

It's hard for me to understand the meaning of "out for" and "caring" in this sentence. Can anyone help me? Thank!

Comment: "He is only out for" means that is his sole purpose. You can find the meaning of *care/caring* in a dictionary.

Comment: It is pointing out that salesmen provide a useful service and that this may be thought of as a kind of "caring". I have known many salesmen who obviously cared about their customers, even though it was their job to sell as much as they could.

Comment: There is no need to thank people (an up-vote is sufficient). It is considered to be "noise" here, but you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> he is only out for selling his products

Google is your friend here:

[image]

The meaning is "He is only intent on selling his products (and not ...)" or, "His only intention is to sell his products (and not ...)

> selling products is not caring

The meaning is "as if *selling products* is not (an action that expresses) *caring*," which is to say, "selling products can be a *caring* activity, even if the traditional view doesn't understand this."